# Разбить текст на предложения C#

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Имеется срочная необходимость разбить русский текст из файла на предложения. Простое деление `(split)` по `.`, `!` или `?` не подойдет. Нужно учитывать варианты сокращений типа т. о., др., т. д.; сокращения перед именем собственным (г. Москва), сокращения типа Иванов И. И. и другие. Сейчас код регулярного выражения выглядит так:

```
string[] splitSentences = Regex.Split(sTemp, @"(?<!\w\.\w.)(?<![A-Z][a-z]\.)(?<=\.|\?)(\s|[A-Z].*)");
```

Понятно, что этого не достаточно. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: как вариант, игнорировать точку по слов из одной или дву букв

Answer (score 1):

Я конечно не могу ручаться за 100% валидные предложения.

```
[А-ЯЁ][\S\s]+?(?:[\S][^А-ЯЁ\.]){1,}(?:\.+|[?!])(?!(\s*[а-яё)\-"«0-9\.]))
```

Но такой вариант подошел на частные случаи г. Москва или Иванов И.И.

*Жду комментариев если какой-то участок вам мозолит глаза!*

[Вот здесь тестировал](https://regex101.com/r/o69Mad/2)

Comment: Что обозначают символы "«

Comment: Для С# не подходит данный шаблон.